# How to limits some users to view Django admin content by default permission

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Am new to Django I have developed app in Django, when I assign view permission allowed to view content

Question is this how can I override default view permission to allow user to his own created content on admin site

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to override `get_queryset(self, request)` in your ModelAdmin. Something like this:

```
@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = YourModel

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.model.objects.all()
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```